# Структура с указателями как аргумент для функции free()

Tags: c, память, malloc, free

Есть код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Data {
    int size;
    char *bin;
};

int main() {
    struct Data *data = (struct Data *) malloc(sizeof(struct Data));
    data->bin = (char *) malloc(3);
    data->size = 3;
    free(data);
}
```

Освободит ли `free(data)` память, на которую указывает `data->bin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, `free()` уничтожает только указатель, который ей передали, ничего внутри него она не трогает.

Comment: То есть мне нужно поочерёдно `free(data->bin); free(data);`, так?

Comment: Да, вы правы, нужно.

Comment: Напишите функции которые будут выделять и освобождать память, так делают на си.